# How to modify position of center?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do I Modify position of "center"? I don't even know how it's called

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHxCZ.png).

[image]

I have tried adjusting pivot point settings but they have no effect. They don't move the blue circle.

I am not dealing with sprites, I have TEXT with a Rect Transform.

The image is just an example.

Comment: Its called "pivot" and you can find this if you even look into unity tutorials.

Comment: @PawełMarecki I have tried adjusting pivot point settings but they have no effect. They don't move the blue circle.

Comment: So you should describe the problem. Tell us what do you want to do, what you done, etc.

Comment: @PawełMarecki Question edited.

Comment: Here you can find useful information about anchoring UI elements. [Unity Manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html) for Unity 5.3

Answer (score 2):

Select the sprite that you want to have a custom pivot (in the `Project` tab). Click on `Sprite Editor`. Move the pivot around. Then drag and drop that asset on the canvas.

I mentioned canvas because of your screenshot. But if you are using `SpriteRenderer` then your best shot is to create an empty `GameObject` and move it in the desired pivot position, then make the sprite a child of the new pivot object.

Comment: I am not dealing with sprites, I have TEXT with a Rect Transform.

Comment: You need to vote up and TICK this excellent answer. `.Text` is the same as `.Image`

Comment: I am agree with @JoeBlow

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a sprite then change your `transform tool` to something other than `sprite selector`.

[image]

If you need to change the pivot of your `textMesh` than change that inside the `inspector`.